# A double integral

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral
$$\iint_D\frac{y}{2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}~\mathrm dx~\mathrm dy$$
where $D$ is the region in the third quadrant between the circles $x^2+y^2=4$, $x^2+y^2=9$ and the lines $y=0$ and $y=x$.

Since D doesn't have smooth bounds, do I need to split this up into 2 integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use polar coordinates.

We have $$I=\iint_D\frac{y}{2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dA$$
$$I=\iint_D \frac{r\sin{\theta}}{2r^2\cos{\theta}}rdrd\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_2^3\int_{\pi}^{5\pi/4}\frac{r\tan{\theta}}{r}drd\theta=\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{\cos{\pi}}{\cos{5\pi/4}})=\frac{1}{4}\ln(2)$$

All credits go to Robert Z for correcting a slight error I made. Had to edit because I cannot delete an accepted answer.

Comment: Made an error somewhere and can't delete now... damn

Answer (score 1):

By using the polar coordinates we get
$$\iint_D\frac{y}{2x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\ dxdy=\int_{\rho=2}^3\int_{\theta=\pi}^{5\pi /4} \frac{\rho\sin \theta}{2\rho^2\cos \theta } \ \rho d\rho d\theta\\=\int_{\rho=2}^3 d\rho\int_{\theta=\pi}^{5\pi/4}\frac{\sin \theta}{2\cos \theta } d\theta=\frac{(3-2)}{2}[-\ln(|\cos\theta|)]_{\theta=\pi}^{5\pi/4}=\frac{\ln(2)}{4}.$$

Comment: Aren't your integrand symbols on the left on the 2nd line the wrong way around since you have dp*dtheta therefore the inner most integrand should be p=2 to p=3

Comment: @gorge Is it better now?